# What is the use of pragma code section and data section?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, pragma, c-preprocessor

What exactly will happen to the data segment and text segment if I use the below two lines in my c source code file?

```
#pragma CODE_SECTION(func1, "Sec1")
#pragma DATA_SECTION(globalvar1, "Sec2")
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Source (contains examples): https://web.archive.org/web/20080803190119/http://hi.baidu.com/jevidyang/blog/item/6d4dc436d87e3a300b55a918.html

Note: `#pragma` is compiler specific, so syntax may vary for your compiler.

The DATA_SECTION pragma allocates space for the symbol in a section called section name.
The syntax for the pragma in C could be:

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION (symbol, "section name");
```

The syntax for the pragma in C++ could be:

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION ("section name");
```

The DATA_SECTION pragma is useful if you have data objects that you want to link into an area separate from the .bss section.

---

The CODE_SECTION pragma allocates space for the func in a section named section name. The CODE_SECTION pragma is useful if you have code objects that you want to link into an area separate from the .text section.
The syntax of the pragma in C could be:

```
#pragma CODE_SECTION (func, "section name")
```

The syntax of the pragma in C++ could be:

```
#pragma CODE_SECTION ("section name")
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "the syntax for this in C/C++ is..."! DATA_SECTION and CODE_SECTION are completely compiler-specific and not supported by any standard at all. What will happen is up to the compiler. I know several compilers that support CODE_SECTION and DATA_SECTION but with a completely different syntax.

Comment: If I change **is** to **could be**, will you remove the downvote then? Of course `#pragma` is compiler specific.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is better. The important thing is not to trick anyone into thinking that this is well-defined by some standard. Though of course the original question is lacking, as there was no specific compiler mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

`#pragma` means "here follows something implementation-defined unique to this compiler". So what will happen depends on the compiler you are using. If the compiler doesn't support this specific pragma, the whole thing will be ignored.

---

In this case it is fairly obvious, however.

`#pragma CODE_SECTION(func1, "Sec1")` means: "func1 should be in program memory, in the memory area called Sec1". Sec1 will be a read-only memory location where the actual code of func1 will be allocated.

`#pragma DATA_SECTION(globalvar1, "Sec2")` means: "globalvar1 should be in data memory, in the memory area called Sec2". Sec2 will be a read/write location where the variable globalvar1 will be allocated.

Comment: Whether #pragama CODE_SECTION is same as #pragma code_seg which is supported in vc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s20kdbse(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @rajaashok Was that a question or a statement? Any actual reason for downvote, or did you just feel like it?