# What are #pragma equivalencies in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, raspberry-pi, pragma

My compiler is ignoring:

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION(..., "iram_init");
```

and

```
#pragma CODE_SECTION(..., ".icode");
```

Where ... is a function.

This is causing segmentation errors when I run the program. 
I suppose this is because this is the incorrect syntax for gcc compiler ? What is the equivalent ?

Thanks

(Context: This is on the raspberry pi in raspian)

Comment: What compiler supports these pragmas? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The code I was given had these in it. I am trying to run said program to test some things i don't really understand.

Comment: check this it might e helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716637/what-is-the-use-of-pragma-code-section-and-data-section

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent are:

```
__attribute__((section(".icode"))) void fct1(int toto) { ... }
__attribute__((section("iram_init"))) int fct2(void) { ... }

__attribute__((section(".var"))) int myvar;
```

*but* take care about your linker script (commonly ".ld" with gnu tools): thoses sections have to be defined and mapped to correct memory

Comment: Is it the same for variables?

Comment: `__attribute__((section(..)))` should be with definition of variable and function, not with prototype or `extern` declaration. (I think you already do correctly, but I prefer to explicit this)

Comment: Where is the linker script, I can't find it in the gcc files? Do i write it myself?

Comment: gnu ld has a default one, used if you don't provide one. You can retrieve it during the linker step of compilation, with `-Wl,--verbose` option for gcc or `--verbose` if you use directly ld. _But_, I also use a RPI with raspbian and I don't need to specify location of code/variable... I think you have to ask another question with code example about why it doesn't works