# VS linker produces two sections with the same name

Tags: visual-studio, portable-executable

I create new section with this code:

```
#pragma section(".new", execute, read, write)
#pragma code_seg(".new")
```

When I open PE file in PeView I can see that two sections with the same name have been created what is the purpose of other section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second pragma specifies a code section where functions are to be allocated (the .new section in your case)

Using #pragma code_seg without a section-name string resets allocation to whatever it was when compilation began.

Comment: Is it possible to instruct linker not to generate other section with the same name?

Comment: I think you can generate 2 sections with the same name as long as they reserve different purpose  (DATA_SECTION vs CODE_SECTION)

Comment: More info can be found also here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716637/what-is-the-use-of-pragma-code-section-and-data-section