# Understanding of #pragma CODE_SECTION

Tags: code-composer

I use ubuntu 20.04, code composer studio 12.00. Can you please explain for me what does it do:

```
#ifdef FLASH
#pragma CODE_SECTION(motor1_ISR, "ramfuncs");
#pragma CODE_SECTION(motor2_ISR, "ramfuncs");
#pragma CODE_SECTION(xint1_ISR, "ramfuncs");
#pragma CODE_SECTION(spi_ISR, "ramfuncs");
#endif
```

I found file `F28069M_ram_lnk.cmd` with this lines, but I also don't understand what does it mean:

```
   ramfuncs         : > RAMM0,
                        LOAD_START(_RamfuncsLoadStart),
                        LOAD_END(_RamfuncsLoadEnd),
                        RUN_START(_RamfuncsRunStart),
                        LOAD_SIZE(_RamfuncsLoadSize),
```

Comment: Hope this would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716637/what-is-the-use-of-pragma-code-section-and-data-section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me:
[What is the use of pragma code section and data section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716637/what-is-the-use-of-pragma-code-section-and-data-section)

In short:

Source (contains examples): https://web.archive.org/web/20080803190119/http://hi.baidu.com/jevidyang/blog/item/6d4dc436d87e3a300b55a918.html

Note: `#pragma` is compiler specific, so syntax may vary for your compiler.

The DATA_SECTION pragma allocates space for the symbol in a section called section name. The syntax for the pragma in C could be:

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION (symbol, "section name");
```

The syntax for the pragma in C++ could be:

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION ("section name");
```

The DATA_SECTION pragma is useful if you have data objects that you want to link into an area separate from the .bss section.